# Why I am getting single quote error in one field value and not in other one on jquery ajax post of json datatype?

Tags: jquery, sql, json

I am trying to post data using ajax in jquery of json datatype. I am using json's stringify method to avoid single quote but It is not doing so for one value but doing other value. I am confused. I tried using replace function also but no use.

Following is my jquery code,

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/QualityComplaintService.asmx") %>/DoesVariantExists",                    
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{categoryId: '" + category.val() + "', subcategoryId: '" + subcategory.val() + "', brandId: '" + brand.val() + "', variant: '" + variant.val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        var d = msg.d;
                        if (d == true)
                        {
                           alert("Variant already exists! Please choose another one.");
                           return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        var parameter = {
                                            categoryId: category.val(),
                                            subcategoryId: subcategory.val(),
                                            brandId: brand.val(),
                                            size: size.val(),
                                            variant: variant.val(), 
                                            chkIsActive: chkActive
                                        };
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/QualityComplaintService.asmx") %>/RegisterVariant",                    
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(msg) {
                                    __doPostBack('<%=btnAdd.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") %>','');
                                }
                            });
                        }                    
                    }
            });
```

When I run the above code, I can insert single quote in size field but when I insert single quote on variant field i get error. But are of same datatype. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first AJAX request you have the following line:

```
data: "{categoryId: '" + category.val() + "', subcategoryId: '" + subcategory.val() + "', brandId: '" + brand.val() + "', variant: '" + variant.val() + "'}",
```

which obviously should be replaced with `JSON.stringify` to avoid the horrible string concatenation which will break as soon as one of the parameters contains some special characters such as a single quote:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 
    categoryId: category.val(), 
    subcategoryId: subcategory.val(), 
    brandId: brand.val(), 
    variant: variant.val()
}),
```

Your second ajax call seems fine as you are properly using the `JSON.stringify` method.

Comment: the problem is in second ajax call only... I get single quote error for variant field and not for size field. What is the problem?

Comment: I can't understand how the problem is in the second AJAX call when in the first you already use `variant.val()` and you haven't used `JSON.stringify`.